# CMake convert unix to windows path

Tags: windows, cmake, msys

I'm trying to convert a unix style MSYS path such as 
`/c/my/path/to/a/folder` 
to a Windows path, or something that CMake would understand, 
e.g `C:/my/path/to/a/folder`.
I'd like it to work on a path that is already correct.

Is there any proper way to do it ?

Note : Please do not mention cygwin's cygpath.

Edit: `file(TO_CMAKE_PATH mypath result)` is not working

Comment: Does not work, means that given `mypath` the output `result` is? Please use `message` commands to debug, e.g. `message(STATUS "result = ${result}"`). Why is your initial path in MSYS format? Why do you need an absolute path? For anything within your project you can use relative paths that cmake will take care to convert into full paths. Can you also print the content of the variable [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables)? It will help to understand which kind of "path grammar" is using cmake in your case.

Comment: I need this type of path because i'm using the devkitpro toolchain and it seems to raise problems if the string isn't in that format (probably some conflict with my MSYS+MinGW installation. It doesn't work in this case as the /c/ is not converted in something cmake understands (here C:/). CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR is using c:/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in CMake functionality for this, but you can write a function/macro to do it:

```
macro(msys_to_cmake_path MsysPath ResultingPath)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^/([a-zA-Z])/" "\\1:/" ${ResultingPath} "${MsysPath}")
endmacro()

set(mypath "/c/my/path/to/a/folder")
msys_to_cmake_path(${mypath} result)

message("Converted \"${mypath}\" to \"${result}\".")
```

Having said that, I agree with Antonio's comment in that it seems unusual to need this in the first place.

Comment: it works correctly on the following tests : Converted "/c/my/path/to/a/folder" to "c:/my/path/to/a/folder".
Converted "c:/my/path/to/a/folder" to "c:/my/path/to/a/folder".
Converted "/home/my/path/to/a/folder" to "/home/my/path/to/a/folder"

Comment: This won't convert paths such as `/mingw64` to `e:/msys2/mingw64`. `cygpath -w` will do that as an external process.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you may wish to consider that MSYS itself will perform the conversion at any boundary between MSYS parent and native child process; thus, in an MSYS shell console:

```
cmd //c echo /c/my/path/to/a/folder
```

would display the appropriately converted path `c:/my/path/to/a/folder`. Additionally, this technique offers the possible advantage that it will emit the *fully* converted native form of a path, such as:

```
cmd //c echo /home/my/path/to/a/folder
```

to yield its native equivalent `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/my/path/to/a/folder`, (assuming your MSYS installation is in the recommended default location, at `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0`).

With the caveat that running MSYS shell without proper initialization, as performed by msys.bat, may not work, (especially when running on 64-bit Windows), you *may* be able to run an equivalent command from within a native process, (such as within CMake), as:

```
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/sh -c 'cmd //c echo /home/my/path/to/a/folder'
```

Note that, if you invoke this from a native process which is itself running within an MSYS console, the initialization will have been correctly performed for the console's own shell process, and should thus propagate through the native process; the issues are more likely to arise if you attempt to invoke MSYS processes directly from a cmd.exe process, in a native Windows console, (or other native container).

Also note that, if the path name in question contains spaces, (never a good idea), you *may* need to enclose it within double quotes:

```
cmd //c echo "/home/my/path with spaces"
```

In this case, some experimentation indicates that the double quotes remain within the cmd output. I'm not entirely certain if this is necessary; you should use your discretion in your own particular usage case.

Comment: Hi, this is quite interesting to know how msys handles paths thanks. The only problem with this solution is that of course it's using msys and hence isn't crossplatform.

Comment: @Lectem Of course it's not cross-platform, but then the MSYS form of path representation is only valid when the platform is MSYS anyway, so this does directly answer your original question. If the platform *isn't* MSYS, then the form `/c/my/path/to/a/folder` likely doesn't have *any* meaningful equivalent, when converted as if it is an MSYS path; if cross-compiling to Windows from any other platform, you likely *shouldn't* be using an MSYS path representation in the first place.